# UI Progress bar not updating until after async method is called

Tags: progress-bar, async-await, mvvm-light

I'm trying to display a simple progress bar while a service loads.  I can't for the life of my figure out why this isn't executing immediately.

View:

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="ProgressBar" 
    IsIndeterminate="True" 
    Visibility="{Binding IsLoading, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisiblityConverter}}"   />
```

View Model:

```cs
private Boolean _isLoading;
public Boolean IsLoading
    {
        get { return _isLoading; }
        set
        {
            Set(ref _isLoading, value);
        }
    }

public SignInViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        IsLoading = false;
        _navigationService = navigationService;
        Username = "";
        SignInCommand = new RelayCommand( SignIn, CanSignIn);
    }

private async void SignIn()
    {

  //    DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() =>
  //       {
               IsLoading = true;
               RaisePropertyChanged("IsLoading");
   //      });

        var response = await OrchestratorContext.Instance.SignInWithPassword(_username, _password);

        if (response.IsSuccessful)
        {
            //     _navigationService.NavigateTo("LandingPage");
        }
    }
```

The progress bar doesn't start loading until after the Sign In function is finished.  I've tried using the dispatcher, and also tried raising the property changed after setting.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the code for `OrchestratorContext.Instance.SignInWithPassword`? The problem might be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best approach, but I got it working by forcing a new thread.  Is there a better approach?

```cs
private void SignIn()
    {
        IsLoading = true;

        Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            var response = await OrchestratorContext.Instance.SignInWithPassword(_username, _password);

            if (response.IsSuccessful)
            {
                DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() =>
                    {
                        _navigationService.NavigateTo("LandingPage");
                    });
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Use `Task.Run` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew` with `async-await`.

Comment: If that works it means that `SignInWithPassword` was running on the UI thread, blocking any UI updates. Does this method display any UI? Please post the relevant code. BTW `RaisePropertyChanged` should be called by a property's setter, not by the code that sets the property

Comment: @Panagiotis, that's exactly the behavior that it was exhibiting.  I was wrong in my thinking that await/async always ran on a new thread (thus would be off the UI thread).  Doing some more research it sounds like this isn't the case, and it may or may not spawn a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You correctly took care that if you want to use await somewhere in your function that this function should be declared async.

However, every async function should return either Task (if it would normally would return void) or Task`<TResult`> if it normally would return TResult.

There is one exception: the event handler can return void instead of Task, however, the event handler still  has to be declared async.

If you follow these rules, your UI remains responsive and the progress bar keeps being updated:

```
private async void Button1_clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    await Signin();
}

private async Task SignIn()
{
    // do some processing
    var response = await OrchestratorContext...
    // do some more processing
}
```

**Note the Task return value of Signin()**

Now during your await the UI remains responsive.